# Creating custom dialogs with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, popup, messagebox

I'm very new to python and tkinter. I would like to create a 'custom' message box to pop up when a function is called (when a button is clicked). I would like to have the following texts in the message box (please see pic). I still need to figure out how to pull all that info into those boxes, but for now, I need to have a messagebox pop on the screen when a button is pressed.
I cant seem to find anything to customize my message box. Please click on the link below to see what I'd like to do:

[RUN INFO-MessageBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3dws.png)

```
def process():
#work_directory = os.path.dirname(sequence_filepath)
message = 'Analyst Initials: ' + '\n' + 'Instrument ID: ' + '\n' + 'Solvent: ' + '\n' + 'Internal Standard: ' + '\n'+ 'Batch No: '
messagebox.showinfo('Run Info', message = message)
return
```

Comment: You can use [`tkinter.simpledialog.Dialog`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) class which support customization.

Answer (score 1):

Their are different types of message boxes

```
showinfo()
showwarning()
showerror ()
askquestion()
askokcancel()
askyesno ()
askretrycancel ()
```

Here is a small Example

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

top = Tk()
def hello():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")

B1 =Button(top, text = "Say Hello", command = hello)
B1.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

You can try this
For your specific problem you can try this

```py
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
def hello():
   root=Toplevel()
   b=StringVar()
   c=StringVar()
   d=StringVar()
   e=StringVar()
   b.set("hi")
   c.set('hellow')
   d.set('yoo')
   e.set('nice')
   l1=Label(root,text='a').grid(row=0,column=0)
   l2=Label(root,text='a').grid(row=1,column=0)
   l3=Label(root,text='a').grid(row=2,column=0)
   l4=Label(root,text='a').grid(row=3,column=0)
   e1=Label(root,font=('arial 16 bold'),textvar=b).grid(row=0,column=1)
   e2=Label(root,font=('arial 16 bold'),textvar=c).grid(row=1,column=1)
   e3=Label(root,font=('arial 16 bold'),textvar=d).grid(row=2,column=1)
   e4=Label(root,font=('arial 16 bold'),textvar=e).grid(row=3,column=1)
   root.mainloop()

B1 =Button(top, text = "Say Hello", command = hello)
B1.grid(row=0,column=0)

top.mainloop()
```

I have created 4 labels and entry you can create 6 or more

Comment: Thank you for the code, but even with my very limited python knowledge, I can do that. But you can only show two arguments. If you look at my pic, you'll see I need to add/pull up 6 different things.

Comment: If you want this kind of figure shown then you can simply create a secondary window in your gui by using```Toplevel()```

Comment: ok I can use toplevel. I get that. But how do I add the texts to that popup window?

Comment: See I am written a small code to do that

Comment: Ujjwal, you're the man! :) Thank you. This will help alot. Thanks so much.
Last questiom why do I need both l1 and e1 variables?

Comment: l1 and e1 variables are nothing you can change them

Comment: If the answer is right please tick by answer

Comment: All `l1` .. `l4` and `e1` .. `e4` are `None` because using `Label(...).grid(...)` will get the result of `grid(...)` not `Label(...)`.  Therefore, those variables are not needed.  Also avoid calling `mainloop()` more than once.